# custom attribute value not save in the Database

Tags: magento2, database, customer, custom-attributes, eav-attributes

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Zend_Validate_Exception;

/**
 * @class CustomerSync
 */
class CustomerSync implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private Config $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * AddressAttribute constructor.`enter code here`
     *
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config              $eavConfig,
        EavSetupFactory     $eavSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function apply(): void
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

        $customerEntity = $this->eavConfig->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute('customer', 'eligible_for_sync', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'label' => 'Eligible for Sync',
            'visible' => false,
            'source' => Boolean::class,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'global' => true,
            'default' => 0,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'sort_order' => 50,
            'position' => 50,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true
        ]);

        $customAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', 'eligible_for_sync');

        $customAttribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'adminhtml_checkout', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']
        ]);
        $customAttribute->save();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

That is my controller to save the attribute value. In Xdebug set the value 1 but not update in the database customer_entity_int table

```
 $customerCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $customerCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', [3,8]);
         if ($customerCollection->getSize() > 0) {
            foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
                $customerId = $customer->getId();
                $data = "1";
                $customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
                $customerData->setCustomAttribute('eligible_for_sync', $data);
                $customer->updateData($customerData);
                $customerResource = $this->customerFactory->create();
                $customerResource->saveAttribute($customer, 'eligible_for_sync');

               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided seems to be missing some necessary parts for updating the attribute value. Here's an updated version of your code that should properly save the attribute value in the `customer_entity_int` table:

```php
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class YourClass
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository)
    {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function updateAttributeValue(): void
    {
        $customerIds = [3, 8];
        $attributeCode = 'eligible_for_sync';
        $attributeValue = 1;

        foreach ($customerIds as $customerId) {
            try {
                $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
                $customer->setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
                $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                // Handle exception if needed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the updated code:

1. You need to inject the `CustomerRepositoryInterface` into your class's constructor.
2. Iterate over the customer IDs and retrieve each customer using the `getById()` method from the `CustomerRepositoryInterface`.
3. Set the custom attribute value using the `setCustomAttribute()` method.
4. Save the customer object using the `save()` method from the `CustomerRepositoryInterface`.

Make sure to adjust the code according to your specific use case, such as the attribute code and the customer IDs you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if the Attribute is created in database , you can find it in `eav_attribute` table.

If the attribute exist change the saving code

```
        $customerCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $customerCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', [3,8]);
         if ($customerCollection->getSize() > 0) {
            foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {

               $customer->setData('eligible_for_sync', 1);
               $customer->save();

               }
            }
```

Magento 2 best practice suggests using the Repository pattern to save data, but for your case , I believe its easier.